# Bluetooth HC-05 module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, embedded, hc-05, arduino-nano

I have two HC-05 modules the first one's role as a Master and the other is a slave one.
I've done some AT commands to set up each HC-05 module

= Master's configuration has to be like that: name=Master, Password=2021, only accept connection from one HC-05 module only (for privacy purposes) via the Slave's Address, Baud rate = 9600,0,0.

= Slave's configuration has to be like that: name=Slave, Password=2021, Baud rate = 9600,0,0.

The AT command I used to set this configuration like that:

Slave:

```
/*Set Slave mode.*/

AT+ROLE= 0

/*Setting up Baud rate (The same as the Master Baud Rate to proper connection).*/

AT+UART= 9600,0,0

/*Rename the module.*/

AT+NAME=Slave.

/*Get the Slave address to save it for Master*/

AT+ADDR?
```

(The response will be the module Address, I will save it for Master configuration)
let it = 98d3:a1:fd7a0f

Master:

```
/*Set master mode.*/

AT+ROLE= 1

/*For secured connection make Master accept only one module via its unique Address.*/

AT+CMODE=0

/*Setting up Baud rate (The same as the Master Baud Rate to proper connection).*/

AT+UART= 9600,0,0

/*Save salve address*/ 

AT+BIND=98d3,a1,fd7a0f 

/*Rename the device.*/

AT+NAME=Master.

/*Change Password.*/

AT+PSWD= 2021
```

I saw a lot of videos the result of all of them is: the two modules are automatically connected to each other when power is on.
but mine is not!

Were I make any mistake!?
these are some videos that I've watched to achieve my goal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgFZE16UKTM&t=31s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXXAcFOTnBo&t=222s

note:

wiring when AT command was Tx->Tx, Rx->Rx, EN->3v3, GND->GND, VCC->VCC.

wiring when normal condition was Tx->Rx, Rx->Tx, EN->(not connected), GND->GND, VCC->VCC.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw a lot of videos the result of all of them is: the two modules
> are automatically connected to each other when power is on. but mine
> is not!

This confuses me, I can't see any command that will let you initiate connection. My guess is that `AT+BIND` is a command for trusting. However `AT+CMODE` is explained as:

> Param1: Connection mode: 0 -> Connect the module to the specified
> Bluetooth address. (Bluetooth address can be specified by the binding
> command)

In this case, I would send `AT+BIND` **first** rather than setting `CMODE`.

If we have a look at [HC-05 AT command list](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/robocore-lojavirtual/709/HC-05_ATCommandSet.pdf), we can see that there are other commands that are used to establish classical Bluetooth connection. I would do the following in order:

1. `AT+PAIR=MAC`
2. `AT+BIND=MAC`
3. `AT+LINK=MAC`

I would also check the status via `AT+STATE?`.